# Webpack resolve.alias OS-specific error

Tags: webpack, centos, vue.js, alias, resolve

I'm currently managing a single page application using Vue.js as front-end framework. All its sources are bundled by webpack through dev and production environment.

Recently I updated webpack module's version from '2.1.0-beta.25' to '2.2.0'. Which works fine in my dev machine (OS X Sierra), but when built in server (CentOS 7), error occurs at the end of webpack build process, such as the following snippets.

```
ERROR in ./src/js/store/Store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js/Defines.js' in '/path/to/project/src/js/store'
 @ ./src/js/store/Store.js 1:0-37
 @ ./src/client.js
```

Specifically, `Defines.js` is located in `src/js`, and this path is set as an alias through webpack configs such as:

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js')
  },
  ...
}
```

In sources I import this module as `import Defines from 'js/Defines.js'`.

This error is very strange to me because it never occurred in previous version of webpack, and I really don't think the `resolve.alias` settings are designed to be applied in OS-specific manner. Also, no similar issue found from documentation.

If anyone had resolved these kind of issues, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for myself.

For anyone who eventually runs into the same path, it does nothing to do with webpack or any other libraries.

My `Defines` module's filename is `src/js/defines.js`, starting lowercased `d`, whereas it is imported as `'src/js/Defines.js` with uppercase `D`. Maybe I changed the filename by mistake. Works fine in OS X, but error in CentOS 7.